# Drag and Drop event using angular4 is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener, angular-directive

I am using a directive to get the files when it is dropped on the HTML element, it is working fine in chrome but it is not working in IE11.
[image]
the following is the code for the drag and drop event
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDragDrop]'
})
export class DragDropDirective {

  constructor() { }
  @Output()
  FileDragEvent: EventEmitter<File> = new EventEmitter<File>();

  @HostListener('window:drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.dataTransfer.items[0].type != 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
      return false;
    }
    let files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    this.FileDragEvent.emit(files);
  }
  @HostListener('window:dragover', ['$event']) public onDragOver(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

  }

  @HostListener('window:dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

  }
}
```

intially i was just using like this for the @hostlistener

```
@HostListener('dragover',
```

but then i read in some blog which asked me to change it to like this

```
@HostListener('window:dragover',
```

I also tried to give min-height to element which has the directive for drag and drop but still i am facing the issue.

the functionality is running smooth in chrome but i am facing issue in IE11

Comment: Any update on this question so far??

Answer (score 0):

removed from some styles `pointer-events: none` for IE 11 and everything seems to work