# How do you call this method ( Angular 5 )?

Tags: angular, typescript

So, i am pretty new to Angular 5 and in my application i have a component that looks something like this:

```
//imports

@Component({
  selector: 'dragdropmagic',
  templateUrl: './dragdropmagic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dragdropmagic.component.css']
})
export class DragDropMagicComponent {

  constructor(/*inject services etc*/) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //init stuff..
  }

  document.getElementById("dragdrop").addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    dragDropMagic(e); /*<--- Throws error "Cannot find name 'dragDropMagic'" */
    this.dragDropMagic(e); /*<--- Throws error "Not valid Property for HTML Element" */
  })

  dragDropMagic(e){
    console.log("Do something...");
  }
}
```

What i am trying to do is call the `dragDropMagic` function inside the EventListener. How can i achieve this? Normally i would call a method with `this.dragDropMagic(e)` unfortunately it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your code must be in a method. And stop using function(). Use arrow functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: that's not even valid javascript code..

Comment: Please format your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try This http://embed.plnkr.co/JbG8Si

Comment: @JBNizet thanks it really needs to be in a method. Why should i use arrow functions? Would it look like this dragDropMagic = (e) => {...}? How would i call it?

Comment: Because that's what allows binding the function to this. Have you clicked on the link to the duplicate?

Comment: yea i will read it this evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `addEventListener`, you can bind the `dragDropMagic` method to the `drop` event of your drop zone in the component template, as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xt9web):

```
<div (dragover)="$event.preventDefault()" (drop)="dragDropMagic($event)">Drop area</div>
```

```
dragDropMagic(event: DragEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Do something...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @HostListener to handle this.

```
@HostListener('window:drop', ['$event'])
public dragDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do your magic;
}
```

And to find out more on this from someone who has really got a great answer see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730364/drag-and-drop-event-using-angular4-is-not-working-in-ie11) as it's very informative and something you can work from to develop your code.